# Correctly bind to Javascript function parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I got a method which receives 2 parameters:

```
function func(param1, param2){...
```

I got a React component which receives a function as a parameter and it has the information about the 2nd parameter, and I want to set the first parameter in this case as a constant.

What I'm doing is:

```
let myFuncToPass = func.bind("const value", null);
.
.
.
<ComponentName funcParam = { (res) => myFuncToPass(res) } 
.
```

I was expecting that when the callback is invoked, the parameter will be called with "const value" as the first parameter and the `res` as the 2nd. What happens is that the res is received as it should to the 2nd parameter, but the first one is null instead of "const value"

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: The first parameter binds `this`, then follow the rest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: @deceze I actually followed exactly that.. I saw the example there with:  var addThirtySeven = addArguments.bind(null, 37);   and just copied that. Why is it working there in the example but not in my case?

Comment: Uhm, no… you're setting `"const value"` as the `this` parameter, and `null` for `param1`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

```
let myFuncToPass = func.bind(this, "const value");
```

[edit] the first argument won't necessarily be `this`, it depends entirely on your usecase -- if `func` never uses `this` internally it probably doesn't matter at all, or you may prefer to pass `null` in -- you'll need to think about that question for yourself

the first argument binds what `this` means when the resulting function is called, and the second argument defines the first argument passed to the function

[edit]

Just do this as an experiment:

```
function x() {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(arguments);
}

x();

x.bind({a:2}, "first argument")("second argument");
```

Comment: For "standalone" functions, `this` should probably be `null`, not `this`.

Comment: Perhaps, but this isn't a standalone function, he's doing it in React and, given that he hasn't posted the rest of his code, it's extremely likely that he's going to be doing something with the state or the props or something.

Comment: Sure, it depends on details we don't see here; but the typical pattern is `foo.bar.bind(foo)` so `bar` doesn't lose its context. Binding a standalone `bar` to a `foo` it didn't belong to is—while entirely possible—not the first conclusion I'd jump to.

Comment: I've made an edit warning him to consider what he binds to `this`

Answer (score 0):

Look to docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Bind function first parameter is *this*.

To use a partial application, you should use babel or a functional library like Ramdajs or write like this.

```
func.bind('irrelevant', 'const value')
```

Comment: *"You __must__ use babel"*…!?